# Linux kernel - Syscall Implentation - Page Table Walk

Tags: linux-kernel, memory, system-calls, kernel-panic

I am trying to learn a few things about the linux kernel and I have come across a kind of exercise which asks to implement two system calls on th 4.15.0+ linux kernel which aim at reading the pages from the page table of a process. The goal is for the first system call to count the number of pages and for the second system call to retrieve a bitmap indicating with 1 all pages that were present in memory and in read-only mode.

After doing some research online, this is what I have come up with:

```
struct task_struct {
   ....
    struct list_head pg_list;
    unsigned long count;
}

#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/list.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/uaccess.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/sched/signal.h>
#include <linux/string.h>
#include <linux/mm.h>

struct page_list{
    size_t num_page;
    struct list_head list;
};


asmlinkage long sys_get(const char *proc_name const size_t name_len){
    char p_name[name_len+1];
    struct task_struct *task;
    struct vm_area_struct *vma = NULL;
    unsigned long vpage;
    unsigned long count = 0;
        
    if (copy_from_user(p_name, proc_name, name_len)) return -EFAULT;
    p_name[name_len] = '\0';
    
    for_each_process(task){
        if(strcmp(task->comm, p_name) == 0) {
            INIT_LIST_HEAD(&task->pg_list);

            if (task->mm && task->mm->mmap) {
                for (vma = task->mm->mmap; vma; vma = vma->vm_next) {
                    for (vpage = vma->vm_start; vpage < vma->vm_end; vpage += PAGE_SIZE) {
                        
                        pgd_t *pgd = pgd_offset(task->mm, vpage);
                        if (pgd_none(*pgd) || pgd_bad(*pgd)) continue;

                        p4d_t *p4d = p4d_offset(pgd, vpage);
                        if (p4d_none(*p4d) || p4d_bad(*p4d)) continue;

                        pud_t *pud = pud_offset(p4d, vpage);
                        if (pud_none(*pud) || pud_bad(*pud)) continue;

                        pmd_t *pmd = pmd_offset(pud, vpage);
                        if (pmd_none(*pmd) || pmd_bad(*pmd)) continue;

                        pte_t *pte = pte_offset_map(pmd, vpage);

                        if (pte_present(*pte) && !pte_write(*pte)) {
                            struct page_list *el = kmalloc(sizeof(*el), GFP_KERNEL);
                            if (!el) return -ENOMEM;
                            el->num_page = count;
                            list_add(&el->list, &our_task->pg_list);
                        }
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}

asmlinkage long sys_get(char *bitmap, const char *proc_name, const size_t name_len){    
    struct list_head *i;
    struct list_head *n;
    struct page_list *el;
    struct task_struct *task;
    char p_name[name_len+1];
        
    if (copy_from_user(p_name, proc_name, name_len)) return -EFAULT;
    p_name[name_len] = '\0';
       
    if (bitmap == NULL) {
        return -ENOENT;
    }
    
    for_each_process(task){
        if(strcmp(task->comm, p_name) == 0){
            list_for_each_safe(i, n, &task->pg_list){
                el = list_entry(i ,struct page_list, list);
                bitmap[el->num_page] = 1;
                list_del(i);
                kfree(el);
            }
            kfree(&task->pg_list);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This does not work as expected and sometimes it causes kernel panic for reason I don't really understand. This is my first time playing with kernel code... A few specific questions I have are: is this a valid way to traverse all pages corresponding to a process, are the macros I use to find read-only present pages correct (x86-32 arch only). What is the right way to wright my results into char *bitmap, since it comes from user space just accessing it is wrong. Finally the kernel panic comes from the way I handle memory, but I am not sure what I do  wrong. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: You have to create the bitmap in kernel space first (e.g. kmalloc), then use `copy_to_user()` to write it into the `bitmap` pointer ...

Comment: @MurrayJensen I was hoping for some more feedback...but I will manage I guess :P